# Error from google adwords api - AttributeError: 'HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout' object has no attribute 'proxy_info'

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client

I've created an MCC account and a Test-account, got developer token and refresh token

After I downloaded "googleads-python-lib-master" folder, I have changed the configuration file "googleads.yaml" to match the following parameters:

```
# Required Fields                                                           #
  #############################################################################
  developer_token: .......
  #############################################################################
  # Optional Fields                                                           #
  #############################################################################
  client_customer_id: ***-***-****
  user_agent: 
  # partial_failure: True
  # validate_only: True
  #############################################################################
  # OAuth2 Configuration                                                      #
  # Below you may provide credentials for either the installed application or #
  # service account flows. Remove or comment the lines for the flow you're    #
  # not using.                                                                #
  #############################################################################
  # The following values configure the client for the installed application
  # flow.
  client_id: ......
  client_secret: .....
  refresh_token: ......
```

Then I run "setup.py" in the folder "googleads-python-lib-master" with the command "python setup.py build install" successfully and installed all necessary modules in the folder "lib/site-packages"

```
[all the modules][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQK8y.png
```

But when I run example scripts such as get_campaigns or add_ad_groups etc. in `"C:\Users\my\python36-32\Lib\site-packages\googleads-python-lib-master\examples\adwords\v201802\basic_operations"`, I always got the error information:

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout' object has no attribute 'proxy_info'
```

Video tutorial from Google Developer dosen´t help
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Check with the stack trace your getting with this issue, https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/issues/261 . It maybe similar.

Comment: @SandeepRVenkatesh Very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: I would like to post that comment as an answer if it resolved your issue, so you could accept it. So, let me know if it did.

Comment: @SandeepRVenkatesh yeap, you could post the answer and I would accept it

Comment: @SandeepRVenkatesh sorry it´s my first time to ask a question on StackOverFlow, could you tell me how can I accept your answer? I didn´t found the 'accept' button :)

Comment: Haha you'd just have to click the tick icon below the arrows. It should show up green once you do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's due to a bug, workaround is to pin the httplib2 package to `httplib2==0.10.3.` Defer to this [link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/issues/261) for more information on the bug.